# Transport an image between two Applications

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, java-ee-7

I have a JEE Web Application(A) with a Bean which reads the metadata from a JPEG image and stores the image in a postgreSQL DB.
This happens, when a user uploads manually a jpeg file with a JSF form.

Now I have a task to provide an interface for another Application(B).
Application(B) makes Screenshots and shall use the interface from Application(A) to store the images in the DB.

I have no idea how i can realize this.
Is it right to make a Remote Session Bean interface with a sendImage method and the Application(B) must implement this method? And how can I transport the file between these two Applications.
I would appreciate if you can give me a hint and point me in the right direction.

Comment: In app A, is the image uploaded from a form or something?

Comment: Yes with a JSF form. But the form has nothing to do with the Application (B). Application (B) has no access to that form. It shall call the interface , when it takes a screenshot.

Comment: Application B could have access to the http endpoint that the form hits though. I'm asking because exposing that endpoint in a http based api is probably your shortest path.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think my mention with the JSF form is irritating. I should have left this out. The Application(B) shall not use the form. (The form was only for testing manually). It must use a given interface from App(A).

Comment: I'm just saying, if you already have the http endpoint, you may also have your interface. No need to trouble with remote session beans, rmi, or any java specific tech.